# Tons of liked comments

Tags: youtube

So, I was on a YouTube video, and I expanded all the sub-comments on the top comment, and all of them were liked by me, even though I never watched the video before. This occurs on all popular videos, only on the top comment. The comments aren't liked until I expand the comments:

**Unexpanded:**

[image: unexpanded]

**Expanded:**

[image: expanded]

*Video from screenshots: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kffacxfA7G4*

Comment: looks like a display bug. Try clearing cache and cookies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[YouTube is aware of this bug. They are working on a fix.](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/youtube/G5UcHOLOqz0/wtloTDGHBAAJ)

Comment: Private communication with a YouTube Employee. There is no publicly available source.

Comment: Found a different source that's public, just for you @zach

Comment: That's from around the same time I posted my question too! So it must be a pretty new bug.